# An extended Freshmans dream

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields, binomial-theorem

If $p$ is prime, then $(x+y)^p=x^p+y^p$ holds in any field of characteristic $p$. (proved with the help of the Binomial Theorem) But now I need to prove that this implies that this is true for any $(a+b+c...+n)^p = a^p + b^p + \cdots + n^p$. The paper says I have to prove it via Induction. I want to prove:

$$(a_1+\cdots+a_n)^p=a_1^p+\cdots+a_n^p$$

Thank you for any answers!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Use induction on the number of terms

Comment: Unless you are only required to prove it for 14 terms, $a$ through $n$ (assuming the English alphabet, anyway...)

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is obviously true for one term and also for two via the binomial theorem. Now, suppose the assertion holds for $k-1$ ($k\ge3$) terms, i.e.

$$(a_1+\cdots+a_{k-1})^p=a_1^p+\cdots+a_{k-1}^p\,.$$

Then

\begin{align*}
(a_1+\cdots+a_{k-2}+a_{k-1}+a_k)^p
&=(a_1+\cdots+a_{k-2}+(a_{k-1}+a_k))^p
\\
&=a_1^p+\cdots+a_{k-2}^p+(a_{k-1}+a_k)^p
\\
&=a_1^p+\cdots+a_{k-2}^p+a_{k-1}^p+a_k^p
\end{align*}

where we first use the induction hypothesis and then the case $k=2$.

Comment: How do I go about including my own proof though? I kind of figured your answer in the back of my head already, but I just a little hint on how to use the induction hypothesis (how do I use k=2) in this case. Thank you very, very much for your quick answer.

Comment: @ilovealgebra I'm not sure if I can follow, but the important part is to notice that a sum of $k$ terms can be expressed as a sum of $k-1$ terms by clever usage of parentheses. We first reduce the number of terms to apply the induction hypothesis and then use the base case ($k=2$) to get rid of the parenthesis we introduced earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Let $S(n)$ be the statement that $(a_1+\dots+a_n)^p\equiv a_1^p+\dots+a_n^p$. We know that $S(1)$ is true trivially, and $S(2)$ is the usual Freshman's dream. Now that we have our base cases, we just need to show that $S(n)$ implies $S(n+1)$ for all $n\ge 2$ to complete the inductive proof.

Assume $S(n)$. To prove $S(n+1)$, note
$$
\begin{aligned}
(a_1+\dots+a_n+a_{n+1})^p
&=(\color{blue}{(a_1+\dots+a_n)}+a_{n+1})^p
\\&\stackrel{S(2)}= (\color{blue}{a_1+\dots+a_n})^p+(a_{n+1})^p
\\&\stackrel{S(n)}= a_1^p+\dots+a_n^p+a_{n+1}^p
\end{aligned}
$$
We have proven $S(n+1)$, so the proof by induction is complete.